# Simpsons Rule 10<-6 Error

Tags: calculus, java

I am making a Java function to calculate $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x/sin(x) dx$ using Simpsons rule. When the function equals $0$ or $0/\sin(0)$ should I just add $1$ (limit) or $10^{-10}$ (limit). My professor said to use $10^{-10}$ why would this be?

```
public static double simpsonsRuleFunction1(double valueN, double valueA, double valueB, double valueDx) {

    double e = 0.0;
    double simpsonsRule = 0.0;
    double valueHolder = 0.0;

    valueN = 2;
    valueA = 0;
    valueB = (Math.PI)/2; 

    for(int i = 1; i<=valueN+1 ; i++){
        valueDx = (valueB-valueA)/valueN;
        e = valueA + ((i-1)*valueDx);

        if (i==1) {
        // Limit as x -> 0
        simpsonsRule += Math.pow(10,-10);

        }
        else if ((i % 2 == 0) && ( i > 1) && (i < valueN+1 ))  {
        simpsonsRule += 4*(e/((Math.sin(e))));
        }
        else if ((i % 2 != 0) && ( i > 1) && (i < valueN+1 )) {
        simpsonsRule += 2*(e/((Math.sin(e))));   
        }
        else if (i == valueN+1 ) {
            simpsonsRule += (e/((Math.sin(e))));

        }

    }
    simpsonsRule = simpsonsRule *((valueDx)/3);

    System.out.println("\nsimpsonsRule" + simpsonsRule);

     while(Math.abs(valueHolder - simpsonsRule) > Math.pow(10,-6)) {
           System.out.println("\nValueHolder" + valueHolder);
           valueHolder = simpsonsRule;
           valueN +=2;
           valueDx = (valueB-valueA)/valueN;
           simpsonsRule = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i<=valueN + 1; i++){
        e = valueA + ((i-1)*valueDx);

        if (i==1) {
        // Limit as x -> 0
        simpsonsRule += Math.pow(10,-10);

        }
        else if (i % 2 == 0) {
        simpsonsRule += 4*(e/((Math.sin(e))));
        }
        else if ((i % 2 != 0) && ( i > 1) && (i < valueN + 1)) {
        simpsonsRule += 2*(e/((Math.sin(e))));   
        }
        else if (i == valueN + 1) {
            simpsonsRule += (e/((Math.sin(e))));

        }

    }
    simpsonsRule = simpsonsRule *((valueDx)/3);


    }
    return valueN;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps your professor meant to use the value obtained by substituting $x=10^{-10}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code by removing redundant checks in `if` statements. You can also pull out the `valueDx` which is constant in the loop:

```
double e = 0.0;
double simpsonsRule = 0.0;
double valueHolder = 0.0;

valueN = 2;
valueA = 0;
valueB = (Math.PI)/2; 

valueDx = (valueB-valueA)/valueN;
simpsonsRule = 1.0 + Math.PI/2;
for(int i = 2; i<=valueN ; i++){
    e = valueA + ((i-1)*valueDx);

    if (i % 2 == 0)  {  //even
        simpsonsRule += 4*(e/((Math.sin(e))));
    }
    else { //odd
        simpsonsRule += 2*(e/((Math.sin(e))));   
    }
}

simpsonsRule = simpsonsRule *((valueDx)/3);
```

Also it looks like you repeat this same loop twice in your code for some reason. I havn't run this so there may still be a few bugs especially in the indices etc but this is homework so I wont do it all for you =). You can look at a python or c variant which does what you want on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule)

The python implementation is particularly close to yours. To answer your question though, you are evaluating between 0 and $\pi/2$. Thus the line:

```
simpsonsRule = 1.0 + (Math.PI)/2
```

corresponds to adding $f(0) + f(\pi/2)$ where $f(x)=\frac{x}{\sin(x)}$. In the limit $f(0)->1$ while $f(\pi/2)=\pi/2$.

Comment: Oh so I would use the limit of f(0) -> 1 When I == 1 instead of 10^-10?

Comment: Yes because f(0)->1. Is it possible your professor misunderstood you when you showed him the code? Also don't forget to go over the indicies since I have not run the above code to see if it works.